# JAXB unmarshalling, guarantee order of elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I'm unmarshalling a sequence of elements with JAXB in a list, see below.

XML-File

```
  <stroke>
    <textPoint x="81.0" y="457.0" p="0.0" e="90.0" a="0.0" />
    <textPoint x="80.0" y="457.0" p="0.0" e="89.0" a="135.0" />
    <textPoint x="81.0" y="455.0" p="0.0" e="86.0" a="135.0" />
    ....
    <textPoint x="228.0" y="475.0" p="0.0" e="57.0" a="122.0" />
    <textPoint x="213.0" y="456.0" p="0.0" e="57.0" a="121.0" />
    <textPoint x="233.0" y="476.0" p="0.0" e="57.0" a="122.0" />
  </stroke>
```

Java-Code

```
private List<TextPoint> textPointList;

@XmlElement(name = "textPoint")
public List<TextPoint> getTextPointList() {
    return textPointList;
}

public void setTextPointList(List<TextPoint> textPointList) {
    this.textPointList = textPointList;
}
```

However, I'm a bit worried about the inherent order of the textPoint-elements, as they are ordered fine in the XML-file, but there is no element (e.g. ID) I could sort them via `propOrder`. Nevertheless, it seems to unmarshal them fine in the same order as in the XML-file, so is there no need to worry about that?

Comment: List<TextPoint> type will preserve the order.

Comment: XML nodes in a document _have_ a definite order ("document order"), unlike SQL where order is imposed only by ORDER BY clauses.  You should  be fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `List` will be populated based on the order the elements appear in the XML on an unmarshal.  When marshalling the order of the elements in the XML will be based on the order of the corresponding objects in the `List`.

Comment: Where can one find a official documentation to your answer? Thanks.

Comment: I also need official documentation. If it is not documented it can be changed at any time. My xml files have to be easily comparable by humans so I have to guarantee order of elements.